# Rounding decimals up PHP if 0.001

Tags: php, rounding

Can You help me to figure this out. I need to round number to cents if there is atleast one 0.001. So it has to be 0.01 or if 1.133 it has to be 1.14. I tried many ways like

```
number_format(round($number, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP), 2);
```

and etc... Still nothing helps.

Comment: echo round(1.95583, 2);  // 1.96

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ceil()`](http://php.net/ceil) to round up. Unfortunately, you can't specify to how many decimals, so you'll have to multiply and divide:

```
$number = ceil($number * 100) / 100;
```

Comment: Omggggg finally.... I CANT BELIEVE IT. Thank you soooo much, was surfing internet for two hours....